# Is it possible to post a List as a parameter for a function with unlimited parameters (...) in Java?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Lets say I have a third party library which exposes a function accepting unlimited parameters:

```
void foo(Bar ... bar);
```

I can not change this library or create new functions for that library, I only can use what they're exposing. Next, I have a list of parameters to use:

```
List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
// list initialization by some complex algorithm.
```

I want to be able to use this list as a parameter for the `foo` function. I know that I can do something like this:

```
for (Bar bar: bars)
    foo(bar);
```

But I need to minimise the number of calls to `foo` as much as possible, so I'm trying to post a whole list at once. Is such thing is possible with Java?

Comment: `ArrayList<Bar>(bar);`?

Comment: Convert the `List`, `bar` to an array, for example, `bar.toArray(new Bar[bar.size()])`

Comment: Sorry, I do not asking how to init a list, The list is already created. I need to pas this list to the foo function.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a variable argument (or [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)) parameter, yes; it is interchangeable with an array.  You just need to create the array.

Using [`List#toArray(T[] arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-), this is straightforward:

```
foo(bar.toArray(new Bar[bar.size()]));
```